# Chrome Extension Rejection - Blue Argon

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sdk, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, chrome-web-store

I am trying to launch a chrome extension and it has been rejected twice. The first time it was rejected it was because I had the "notifications" permission and it said that I didn't need to declare it and it would still work. The first rejection took about a week because its a big chrome extension and in that time I had to restructure some other things. Once I submitted it again 2 days ago it failed again and I got the following error message through the email:

Violation(s):

Violation reference ID: Blue Argon

Technical Requirements - Additional Requirements for Manifest V3:

Violation: Including remotely hosted code in a Manifest V3 item.
Violating Content:
Code snippet: firebase/gstatic.com_firebasejs_8.10.0_firebase-auth.js: https://screenshot.googleplex.com/7shBZUuDKYAaiVa https://screenshot.googleplex.com/BuuCj3CgQqGawNF https://screenshot.googleplex.com/5VRj5KXYZ3xwmbk https://screenshot.googleplex.com/AN7RPyUAKg9gXr8 https://screenshot.googleplex.com/4m3aMjaSmdoc6WM https://screenshot.googleplex.com/BV2zJLvT7X7ex2W https://screenshot.googleplex.com/58LHABwr8v5vinj
How to rectify: Ensure that all logic related to the extensions operation is included in the extension package. For more information please refer to the documentation on removing remotely hosted code & migration checklist on Manifest V3 version.

The additional; restructuring of the code didn't add anything new or really change anything. It just achieved all the same things it was doing in a different way. This new error is saying that I have external code that I am accessing and referring to my SDK firebase connection. The line it is referring to is part of what is below:

```
importScripts('firebase/gstatic.com_firebasejs_8.10.0_firebase-app.js');
importScripts('firebase/gstatic.com_firebasejs_8.10.0_firebase-database.js');
importScripts('firebase/gstatic.com_firebasejs_8.10.0_firebase-auth.js');
```

That's right it only had a problem with one of the lines but the other two were fine. This doesn't make any sense as all of these imports are the same not to mention they are all referring to local files that I am submitting as part of my chrome extension package. This has to be a mistake for these reasons and the fact that the other time I submitted it had no problem with this line that did not change, right?

**If it is a mistake what do I do I can't remove the line and resubmit it because then it wouldn't work. Do I just resubmit the same thing?**

**Is it not a mistake?**

Thank you.